Setting compilation options with CMake from values coming from a dynamically generated file
I want to set a compilation option -DVAR=xxx. I know that I can do this with target_compile_options but my issue is that the value xxx has to be dynamically generated and is only available as the content of a txt file.
Here is my attempt:

create a custom command that generates the file holding the value to be used
create a custom target that allows to build the var.txt file
create a dependency in order to be sure that the var.txt will be generated before the compilation of MyExe

but I don't kwow how to retrieve the required value from the file and use it in target_compile_options.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project ("MyProject")

add_custom_command (
  OUTPUT  var.txt
  COMMAND echo "123" > var.txt      # just an example here, the real generation is more complex
  COMMENT "Generate variable value"
)

add_executable         (MyExe main.cpp)
target_compile_options (MyExe PUBLIC -DVAR=???)  # how to get the content of "var.txt" for setting VAR ?

add_custom_target (var   ALL DEPENDS var.txt)
add_dependencies  (MyExe  var)

Is it possible for target_compile_options to use values retrieved from a generated file ?


Is it possible for target_compile_options to use values retrieved from a generated file ?

Yes, but no time travel. add_custom_command is executed on build stage, compile options are set on configuration stage, and configuration stage runs before build stage. See cmake introduction.
You can execute the command with execute_process and parse it in CMake language (consider JSON) and extract compile flags during configuration stage in CMake and set them normally with target_compile_definitions.
